# (node:19502) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I have integrated cucumber with `nightwatch.js`.

My package.json looks like:-

```
{
  "name": "learning-nightwatch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "learning nightwatch",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "nightwatch": "nightwatch",
    "start": "bin/start",
    "stop": "bin/stop",
    "test": "bin/test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.16",
    "cucumber": "^3.1.0",
    "nightwatch-cucumber": "^8.2.9"
  }
}
```

**nigtwatch config:-**

```
{
    "src_folders": [null],
    "output_folder": "reports",
    "custom_commands_path": "",
    "custom_assertions_path": "",
    "page_objects_path": "./pageObjects",
    "globals_path": "",
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "launch_url": "http://localhost:8083",
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": true,
                "on_failure": true,
                "on_error": true,
                "path": "./screenshots"
            },
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "marionette": true,
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": ["start-fullscreen"]
                }
            },
            "silent": true
        },
        "firefox": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "firefox",
                "args": ["-headless"]
            }
        }
    },
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "./bin/lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar",
        "log_path": "",
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./bin/lib/chromedriver",
            "webdriver.gecko.driver": "./bin/lib/geckodriver"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run test cases using yarn nightwatch. It runs the test cases successfully but application never terminates with exit code 0and shows message below :

```
4 scenarios (4 passed)
8 steps (8 passed)
0m05.510s
(node:19502) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
(node:19502) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Anyone knows why I am getting this error?

Comment: Clearly, somewhere you're trying to do `xyz.indexOf` when `xyz` is `undefined`. That causes an error which ends up causing a promise to be rejected, and the code isn't handling that rejection. You'll want to find the statement containing `xyz.indexOf` and fix it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have done nothing like that anywhere in my code. To clarify I just have one google search test case added only that contains no indexof

Comment: Lovely... Good luck with it!

Comment: This doesnt make sense: `"src_folders": [null],`, why you have an array with a null value inside?

Comment: this is not the issue i checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 suggestions:

- Try to remove `src_folders`.
- Try to follow http://mucsi96.github.io/nightwatch-cucumber/#getting-started
- Check out https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber-example